# Add Column to Start of CSV

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I would like to add a column to the beginning of the .csv file I am creating in the included script, for "Server Names" that has the value of $serverName in the foreach loop.

This way, the CSV will include "Server Names" with the server name at the beginning of each row and then will display the information that it is pulling from the xml file.

What is the best way to approach this?  Thanks!

```
$localPath = "C:\Temp\MPOS"

$serverList = (Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like 'Q0*00*'" -SearchBase "OU=MPOS,OU=Prod,OU=POS,DC=company,DC=NET").name | Sort-Object | Out-File C:\Temp\MPOS\MPOSServers.txt

$serverNames = Get-Content $serverList

foreach ($serverName in $serverNames) {

    Add-Content $logfile "Processing $serverName" 

    $serverCsv = $serverNames | 

        #Check if the server is online before doing the remote command
        If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $serverName -Quiet -count 1) {

            #copy config file from MPOS print to local server for processing
            $configPath = "\\$($serverName)\D$\mposdevices\deviceconfig.xml"
            Copy-Item $configPath $localPath 

            #process xml file to output data to csv file
            $xml = Get-Content C:\Temp\MPOS\DeviceConfig.xml
            $xmldata = [xml]$xml
            $xmldata.DeviceConfig.ChildNodes | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\MPOS\MDATInfo.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append

        } #If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $serverName -Quiet -count 1) {

} #foreach ($serverName in $serverNames) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the amended script below. I've removed the `$serverCsv = $serverNames |` line as the pipe didn't appear to piping into anything.

I've added this `| Select @{Name="ServerName"; Expression={ $serverName }}, *` between your csv list and the export. This introduces a new `ServerName` variable that holds your current `$serverName` from the loop. The `*` brings through the rest of the fields from your csv list.

```
$localPath = "C:\Temp\MPOS"

$serverList = (Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like 'Q0*00*'" -SearchBase "OU=MPOS,OU=Prod,OU=POS,DC=company,DC=NET").name | Sort-Object | Out-File C:\Temp\MPOS\MPOSServers.txt

$serverNames = Get-Content $serverList

foreach ($serverName in $serverNames) {

    Add-Content $logfile "Processing $serverName"

        #Check if the server is online before doing the remote command
        If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $serverName -Quiet -count 1) {

            #copy config file from MPOS print to local server for processing
            $configPath = "\\$($serverName)\D$\mposdevices\deviceconfig.xml"
            Copy-Item $configPath $localPath 

            #process xml file to output data to csv file
            $xml = Get-Content C:\Temp\MPOS\DeviceConfig.xml
            $xmldata = [xml]$xml
            $xmldata.DeviceConfig.ChildNodes | Select @{Name="ServerName"; Expression={ $serverName }}, * | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\MPOS\MDATInfo.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append

        } #If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $serverName -Quiet -count 1) {

} #foreach ($serverName in $serverNames) {
```

Comment: That does add the requested column at the beginning of the .csv, but it also adds a bunch of unnecessary columns at the end.  How can I just have the ServerName column?  Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: It'll be the `*` that's causing that. I'm not sure what's in `$xmldata.DeviceConfig.ChildNodes`. Instead of `*`, add specific columns

Comment: Cool. No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this would be to stay within the pipeline.

What you want to do:

- find computers in AD
- sort them
- for each of them, produce output object (names and values)
- export those to CSV

Which would look like this:

```
Push-Location "C:\Temp\MPOS"

Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like 'Q0*00*'" | Sort-Object Name | ForEach-Object {
    $serverName = $_.Name
    Add-Content MDATInfo.log "Processing $serverName"
    Write-Host "Processing $serverName"

    $line = @{
        serverName = $_.Name
        foo = ""
        bar = ""
        baz = ""
    }

    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.Name -Quiet -Count 1) {
        $deviceConfigXml = [xml](Get-Content "\\$serverName\D$\mposdevices\deviceconfig.xml")
        $deviceConfig = $DeviceConfigXml.DeviceConfig
        $line.foo = $deviceConfig.foo
        $line.bar = $deviceConfig.bar
        $line.baz = $deviceConfig.baz
    }

    New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop $line
} | Export-Csv MDATInfo.csv -NoTypeInformation

Pop-Location
```

Notes:

- `Push-Location` and `Pop-Location` allow you to work with relative paths in the rest of the script
- no need to write the server names to a file, you can directly work with the server objects
- no need to copy the XML file from the server, you can open it straight from the remote location
- the script ensures that the output object will always be uniform - same number of properties regardless of XML content or server availability
- The last value in the `For-Each` script block is placed onto the output pipeline
- The key line is `New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop $line`.
  It produces a `PSObject`, which is the kind of object that `Export-Csv` can understand